# Basic Auth in swagger using swagger-ui in node express server

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, swagger-ui, basic-authentication

I am trying to set up basic authentication to my api written in nodejs using express.
Below is my swagger.json

```
{
"openapi": "3.0.0",
"components":{
"securitySchemes":{
  "basicAuth":{
    "type":"http",
    "scheme":"basic"
  }
}
},
"securityDefinitions":{
"basicAuth":{
  "type":"basic"
}
},
"security":{
  "basicAuth":[]
},
"servers": [
{
  "url": "http://localhost:3007/api",
  "description": "localhost"
}
],
"paths": {
"/create": {
  "post": {
    "security":{
      "basicAuth":[]
    },
    
    "requestBody": {
      "content": {
          "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/definitions/Model"
              }
          }
      }
  },
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "success"
      },
      "500": {
        "description": "Internal Server Error"
      }
    }
  }
}
 },
 "definitions": {
"Model":{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
      "id": {
          "type": "string"
      }
     
      
  }
 }  }
}
```

And i have also added the options in my server.js where i use swagger-ui-express, below is the code

```
     const swaggerUiOptions = {
   swaggerOptions: {
    basicAuth: {
      name:   'Authorization',
      schema: {
        type: 'basic',
        in:   'header'
      },
      value:  'Basic <user:password>'
    }
  }
}
app.use("/api/tax/swagger", swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument,swaggerUiOptions));
```

Here swaggerDocument is swagger.json.
I am unable to pass basic authorization through swagger. Kindly guide me as where i went wrong.

Comment: Hey, any luck on this issue?

Comment: Nope not yet @ncesar